# Do large creatures have reach?

Tags: dnd-5e, creature-size, reach

Does a large creature (ogre) have reach with their weapons (club) or can they only hit opponents directly adjacent to them?

The *Monster Manual* says the ogre has a 5' reach. Does that mean it only reaches right next to it or is it an additional 5' for a total of a 10' reach?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Check the stat block; it varies from creature to creature

Ogres have the standard 5-foot reach with their greatclub, and javelin if using it in melee, and can only attack melee targets within 5 feet. *MM*, p. 237.

Other creatures, typically larger than size Medium, may have melee attacks with greater than 5-foot reach, which is noted in their descriptions. (*PHB*, p. 195.)

For example: the Large-sized Pit Fiend has a mace with 10-foot reach. (*MM*, p. 77.)